# Ошибка "linker command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток. У меня случилась такая неприятность: я разбирался в своем беспорядке файлов в Finder, и переместил все мои Xcode проекты в одну папочку, и теперь ничего не работает. При запуске приложения на iOS Simulator Xcode выдает такую ошибку:

ld: file not found: /Users/Ruslan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calls-hlhsyihopkugutdgqycqdplhqqoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CallMe.app/CallMe

Как это решить? В интернете нашел решение типа в Project -> Build phases -> Compile Sources добавить недостающие или удалить лишние файлы .m, но у меня они не повторяются и нет недостающих. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте очистить проект, возможно там застряла какая-то ссылка на старую директорию, ну и симулятор до кучи хотя он тут и не при чем. Если не поможет, откройте файл проекта в текстовом редакторе и поищите файлы с абсолютным путем, возможно где-то ссылка не туда. Раньше такое постоянно было с фаилами локализации, с сырцами не видел, но мало ли

Comment: А какой именно файл открыть в текстовом редакторе? Файл проекта - это файл с расширением .xcodeproj?

Comment: xcodeproj это пакет, а не файл, настоящий файл проекта внутри него и называется project.pbxproj

Comment: Я вообще за то, чтобы все файлы, относящиеся к проекту, лежали в проекте. Вот настройка для этого Preferences->Location->Derived Data-Relative ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/7EjZCIm.png

Comment: Я решил проблему, суть была в том, что я когда наводил порядок во всех своих документах, я не переместил папку с проектом, а скопировал и вставил, а оригинал удалил, а копия проекта ссылалась на файл в оригинале, которого, по сути, уже и нету.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Решил поделиться, возможно, это спасет кому-то неделю времени, именно столько потратил я на решение этой проблемы.

Если вы получаете ошибку linker command failed with exit code 1

Внимательно изучите строки, которые идут выше. Если там есть упоминание про armv7, тогда в Valid Architectures в настройках вашего проекта и таргета уберите это значение.